# Class selector and '&' together in SASS

Tags: css, sass, composer-php

We all know this works in sass:

```
body
  margin: 0

  &.active
    margin: auto
```

But when I try to do the following, where the parent is just a class selector, it stops working, compiler is skipping the "&" block, any idea why?

```
.loggedIn
  margin: 0

  &.active
    margin: auto
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  If you're not using the official Sass Ruby compiler, the appropriate thing to do is file a bug report with whoever maintains the compiler you're using.

Comment: This is simply not true. You can prove this to yourself very easily: http://sassmeister.com/ https://gist.github.com/meagar/85ada080b9662370347b

Comment: @meagar Looks pretty non-reproducable to me, it generates the expected results in Sassmeister.

Comment: @cimmanon I wasn't replying to you. My links all support the fact that this is not reproducible.

Answer (score -2):

OK turns out that it was caused by a comment line above &.login line that was not indented as the rest, now I know I have to follow the indentation for comment as the rest of the content.

**This doesn't work:**

```css
/* Container */
.container
    position: relative
    z-index: 1

/* > Login */
    &.login
        width: 320px
        left: 0
        right: 0
        top: 100px
        background: white
        border: 1px solid #E0E0E0
        box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175)
        opacity: 0.90
```

**This works**

```css
/* Container */
.container
    position: relative
    z-index: 1

    /* > Login */
    &.login
        width: 320px
        left: 0
        right: 0
        top: 100px
        background: white
        border: 1px solid #E0E0E0
        box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175)
        opacity: 0.90
```

Comment: Please stop using the live code editor to add sass code. It's for html, CSS and javascript.